# Printing byte array image to printer

Tags: asp.net

I have byte array image and want to print/send it to printer through my web application.

How can I print that byte array to my local printer through web app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you're limited to printing capabilities of the browser, and those capabilities are not particular fantastic.  A typical approach is to utilise a client-side plugin and format your 'response' to the browser to work with that plugin.

One example is creating an Adobe PDF and passing that as your response to the client.  Here's an [example using a free library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20640/Creating-PDF-Documents-in-ASP-NET).